# How to send requests to a testnet faucet to collect coins at my address?

Tags: testnet, buy-bitcoins, faucets

I am really new to Bitcoin and have just started reading about it.

From what I understand testnet Bitcoin can only be requested every 12 hours or so and yields a very low quantity. I would like to build a bot, so to say, which sends a request every 12 hours or so to a testnet faucet.

What I am looking for is a way to send a get/post request, so I can use shell script  or javascript to source the tBTC.

Could anybody point the right direction out to me.

What is the link? How to send the request? If there's a github repo about something related? Any documentation?

Any of these answers would be really helpful to me!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the github projects for this argument (also the question on the project here is off topic).

> I would like to build a bot

Why do you want to create a bot to request the tBitcoin? you have needed a big quantity of bitcoin for your application test?
if yes I think this is not a correct street, the Bitcoin testnet is a network for the developers and in this network, the money is mined my a low difficulty.
So for the respect of other developers if you have neet big quantity of tBitcoin to do mine it. ([a reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/cyotrr/i_can_mining_on_bitcoin_testnet_network_with_my/) for do it).

Another possibility is using the regtest network od bitcoin, (you can build your local network, [a reference](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode) of regtest)

> What is the link? How to send the request? If there's a github repo about something related? Any documentation?

However, these reference of the faucet bitcoin testnet are available [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Testnet) but the request depend of the site that implements the faucet